# How can I generate an AndroidManifest.xml from an existing react-native project?

Tags: android, react-native, npm, expo

I already have a react-native app created and I wanna access the user's geolocation. Well, I don't have any Android's folder and I need to add some permissions in AndroidManifest.xml. How can I tie this into my existing project?

Obs: I am using expo and npm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AndroidManifest.xml` not possible with an Expo project. In order to add this permission, you would have to use the [Bare workflow](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/)

If not you can eject your project from expo or create a new project with `react-native-cli` and move your source code to it.

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot!

Comment: @Ktj If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

Expo has evolved quite a bit in recent years and you can now (Expo SDK 41+) use [config plugins](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/) to change your `AndroidManifest.xml` and still remain in the managed workflow. You will lose the ability to use the Expo Go App, but you can use EAS builds to build a custom dev client, which is basically a version of Expo Go tailored to your project.

The docs provide an [example](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/#modifying-the-androidmanifestxml) of how to use the `withAndroidManifest` mod to modify permissions. Note that you can run `expo prebuild --no-install` to test the effects of your plugin, but be sure to delete the generated native folders before running the EAS build, otherwise EAS will assume bare workflow.

Answer (score 1):

The below codes worked for me!

```
state = {
  isLoading:false,
  location:null,
  errorMessage:null,
  isDevice:"",
}

async componentDidMount() {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android' && !Constants.isDevice) {
    this.setState({
      errorMessage:"oops, this will not work on sketch in an android emulator.Try it on your device!"
    });
  } else {
    this._getLocationAsync();
  }
}

_getLocationAsync = async () => {
  let { status} = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
  if (status !== 'granted') {
    this.setState({
      setError:'Permission to access location was denied'
    });
    
  }
  let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
  this.setState({
    location
  })
  
  console.log(location)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to edit `AndroidManifest.xml` with [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/), followed by using [`apksigner`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner) to re-sign the apk with credentials from `expo credentials:manager`.

To edit the existing manifest:

```sh
apktool decode myapp-original.apk
vim myapp-original/AndroidManifest.xml
```

To re-build a new signed apk:

```sh
apktool build myapp-original -o myapp.apk
expo credentials:manager -p android
/path/toAndroid/Sdk/build-tools/$VERSION/apksigner sign -ks @username__myapp.bak.jks myapp.apk
```